# How to filter out all the row with NA series?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, na

We would like to manage the NAs rows from a dataset (`df`). The scope is filter out the rows with last the follow patterns in the last three columns (`col_3, col_4, col5`):

- the `c(NA, NA, value)`.
- the `c(NA, value, value)`.
- the `c(value, value, value)`.

The final output format shows the final result desired. The R session version is `4.2.0`.

### Input data

```r
library(tibble)
df <- data.frame(
  names =  c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  type_col = c("u", "p"),
  col_1 = c(NA, 30L, NA, NA, 81L, 152L, 7L, NA, NA, 8L),
  col_2 = c(10, 55L, NA, NA, 30L, 8L, 63L, NA, NA, 35L),
  col_3 = c(33L, NA, NA, 55L, 5L, NA, 71L, NA, 15, NA),
  col_4 = c(5L, 41L, NA, 210L, 11L, NA, NA, NA, 14L, 2L),
  col_5 = c(9L, 56L, 112L, 84L, 29L, 3L, 71L, 6L, 19L, 30L)) %>%
  as_tibble()
```

## Input data:

```r
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 7

   names type_col col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
   <chr> <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 a     u           NA    10    33     5     9
 2 b     p           30    55    NA    41    56
 3 c     u           NA    NA    NA    NA   112
 4 d     p           NA    NA    55   210    84
 5 e     u           81    30     5    11    29
 6 a     p          152     8    NA    NA     3
 7 b     u            7    63    71    NA    71
 8 c     p           NA    NA    NA    NA     6
 9 d     u           NA    NA    15    14    19
10 e     p            8    35    NA     2    30
```

## Desired output data

```r
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 7

   names type_col col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
   <chr> <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1 a     u           NA    10    33     5     9
 2 b     p           30    55    NA    41    56
 5 e     u           81    30     5    11    29
 6 a     p          152     8    NA    NA     3
 7 b     u            7    63    71    NA    71
10 e     p            8    35    NA     2    30
```

### Question

Any idea how I could obtain this filter? The final dataset (`df`) had to exclude only the `3`, `4`, `8` and `9` rows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (I am not very sure about the filtering conditions you want, since your text is not very clear):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(if_all(c(p_3:p_5, u_3:u_5), ~ !is.na(.x))) %>% 
  filter(if_any(p_1:p_2, is.na) & if_any(u_1:u_2, is.na))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 11
#>   col_1   u_1   u_2   u_3   u_4   u_5   p_1   p_2   p_3   p_4   p_5
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 a        NA    NA    10     9   152    NA    NA     8     3    10
#> 2 e        81    NA    30    29    10    NA    NA    35    30    16
```

Comment: @MiquelVázquez-Santiago: That is not very clear what you need. Could you please elaborate a bit about that?

Comment: Thanks to the solution proposed @PaulS. The scope of the issue is, independetly of the number of the columns, as follows: i) `NA, NA, value`, ii) `NA, value, value`, iii) `value, value, value`. The exclusion criteria only has two points to taking into account: i) the code should be independent of the number of columns (five for each type in this case, but could be more), and ii) exists two type of columns `u` and `p`.

Comment: @MiquelVázquez-Santiago: The filtering criteria for the last 3 columns should be, I guess: i) `NA, NA, value`, ii) `NA, value, value`, iii) `value, value, value`. Are there any other filtering criteria?

Comment: There is no other filtering criteria @PaulS.

Comment: @MiquelVázquez-Santiago: Imagine the following situation: The last u columns are `NA, NA, value`; should the last p columns be also i) `NA, NA, value`? Moreover, do the column names have the same pattern, that is, `u_1`, `u_2`, ..., `u_200` and by this sequential order?

Comment: Correct, both types of columns have the same pattern of NAs and values, soo whe the`u` columns shows `NA, NA, value` the `p` columns shows `NA, NA, value`;  and the names of the columns always follow the same pattern (`type`, underslash and `number`), so `u_1`, `u_2`, ..., `u_200`.

Comment: @MiquelVázquez-Santiago: Following these criteria, all rows of your example dataset will remain after filtering, right?

Comment: No, take into account the rules shown after, only `b` and `c` rows should be remain into the dataset, because in the other ones, the three patterns are shown into the five `u` and into the five `p` columns.

Comment: @MiquelVázquez-Santiago: I do not quite understand that, as all criteria i), ii) and iii) are fulfilled by all rows of your dataset. For instance, why should not row `a` appear after filtering? In case of row `a`, pattern ii) is fulfilled!

Comment: I've updated the exemple for better understanding. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: @MiquelVázquez-Santiago: I am afraid, it is still too confusing: For instance, why does not row 4 appear in the expected result, since `c(55, 210, 84)` fulfills criterion iii)? Moreover, why is row 7 in the expected result, when `c(71, NA, 71)` violates all criteria?

Comment: Because the data shows a serie of values. Only series with a ```large``` number of values are preserved (this is the case of row ```7```). And the shortest ones, defined by the user, are excluded (this is the case of the row ```4```).

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you want. Maybe some other person can help you.